# Good distribution for modelling age in a population

Tags: distributions, population

What is a good distribution for describing the age structure of a population? For example, if I want to know the probability that a member of a population is less than or equal to 20. How can I parameterize this given that I know the mean and perhaps the standard deviation of a sample?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the empirical cumulative distribution function. This is a non-parametric way of describing the distribution of age in your population. The estimate of the proportion of the population having age less than or equal to 20 would then be just the proportion of your *sample* having age less than or equal to 20.